# Configure CRON to use a particular MTA

Tags: ubuntu, cron, email-server

I have one server on which cron jobs are ran. I don't want to install sendmail or postfix on this server but still want to get mails from cron. 
I have installed Heirloom mailx (http://heirloom.sourceforge.net) and configured it to use the smtp of on an other server I have, with postfix installed and configured to relay my mails.
It works well if I use *mail* from the command line.

Unfortunately this does not seem enough for cron, in my syslog I can see:

> CRON[30869]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

How can I "tell" cron to use this set up to send mails ?

If it matters, I am on Ubuntu 12.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cron relies on local sendmail mechanism to send mails.

Use lightweight smtp server: nullmailer, ssmtp as a local sendmail replacement.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to set this up?

Comment: What an absolute non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think cron is using /usr/sbin/sendmail so make sure you point that to your MTA.